# Cannot login in as root user after MySQL installation (RHEL)

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I am new to MySQL.
I installed MySQL (version 8) in RHEL 7.7 using yum . Now , I am trying to configure MySQL.

```
[root@devdbvm278 ~]# cat /etc/my.cnf
# commented lines removed for readability
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Once the installation was done, I started the mysqld using

```
# systemctl start mysqld
```

Now, when I try to log in as root user, I get the following error.
I tried to fix it using some stuff I found from googling. But, no luck. 
Any idea what is wrong ?

```
[root@devdbvm278 ~]# mysql -u root
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

[root@devdbvm278 ~]# mysql
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
[root@devdbvm278 ~]# 

[root@devdbvm278 ~]# mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
-bash: mysqld_safe: command not found

[root@devdbvm278 ~]# mysqld --skip-grant-tables
2019-08-13T15:53:33.812294Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.17) starting as process 19578
2019-08-13T15:53:33.815432Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010123] [Server] Fatal error: Please read "Security" section of the manual to find out how to run mysqld as root!
2019-08-13T15:53:33.815507Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2019-08-13T15:53:33.815777Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.17)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
[root@devdbvm278 ~]# 


# mysqld --version
/usr/sbin/mysqld  Ver 8.0.17 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the [security](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/default-privileges.html) section of the documentation it states:

> If you do not know the initial random password, look in the server
>   error log.

Try running the following command. It works for me on my 5.7 installation (which has the same instructions as the 8.0 version of the documentation):

```
sudo grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log
```

It should tell you the initial password to use for root.